# Why when I send an email via FastAPI-mail, the email I receive displays the same message twice?

Tags: python, html, email, fastapi

I am trying to send an email using `FastAPI-mail`, and even though I am successfully sending it, when I open the email in Gmail or Outlook, **the content (message) appears twice**.

I am looking at the code but I don't think I am attaching the message twice (also note that the top message always shows the tags, while the second doesn't (see below image).

Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

`main.py`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi_mail import FastMail, MessageSchema, ConnectionConfig
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import EmailStr, BaseModel
from typing import List
app = FastAPI()


class EmailSchema(BaseModel):
   email: List[EmailStr]


conf = ConnectionConfig(
   MAIL_USERNAME='myGmailAddress',
   MAIL_PASSWORD="myPassword",
   MAIL_FROM='myGmailAddress',
   MAIL_PORT=587,
   MAIL_SERVER="smtp.gmail.com",
   MAIL_TLS=True,
   MAIL_SSL=False
)


@app.post("/send_mail")
async def send_mail(email: EmailSchema):

    template = """
        <html>
        <body>
        

<p>Hi !!!
        <br>Thanks for using <b>fastapi mail</b>!!!</p>


        </body>
        </html>
        """

    message = MessageSchema(
        subject="Fastapi-Mail module",
        recipients=email.dict().get("email"), # List of recipients, as many as you can pass
        body=template,
        subtype="html"
        )

    template = """
<p>Hi !!!
<br>Thanks for using <b>fastapi mail</b>!!!
</p>"""

    '''
    template = """
<p>Hi !!!
<br>Thanks for using <b>fastapi mail</b>!!!
</p>"""
    '''

    fm = FastMail(conf)
    await fm.send_message(message)

    return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"message": "email has been sent"})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `body`, use the `html` property.

```
message = MessageSchema(
    subject="Fastapi-Mail module",
    recipients=email.dict().get("email"), # List of recipients, as many as you can pass
    html=template, # <<<<<<<<< here
    subtype="html"
)
```